# Is it possible to have the value in a variable stay the same, even when the object changes?

Tags: c#, code-behind

For instance, I have something like this:

```
MyFirstSess = ((string)Session["WindowName"]);
```

and then later on I have:

```
MySecondSess = ((string)Session["WindowName"]);
```

The object (for me) is to check the WindowName at various points in a function.  However, every time I try to compare them they're equal.  So, I'm trying to figure out how to store MyFirstSess so that it never changes, even if it's object (in this case, ((string)Session["WindowName"]);) does.

Is this possible?

EDIT:  Full code:

```
public partial class PreventMultipleWindows : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string MyFirstSess;
    public string MySecondSess;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyFirstSess = ((string)Session["WindowName"]);

       string MySess = ((string)Session["WindowName"]);
        if (MySess != null)
        {
            MySecondSess = ((string)Session["WindowName"]);
        }

        if (MyFirstSess != MySecondSess)
        {
            string WindowName = "InvalidPage";
            Session["WindowName"] = WindowName;
            return;
        }


    }

    public string GetWindowName()
    {
        string WindowName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "");
        Session["WindowName"] = WindowName;
        return WindowName;
    } 

}
```

Comment: *every time I try to compare them they're equal.* And they're not equal when debugging the code? The assignment doesn't change your variable.

Comment: Why would `Session["WindowName"]` change between the start of `Page_Load` and the comparison?  I can't see many situations where they wouldn't be equal

Answer (score 2):

That's already the behavior that you have.  Changes to the session value won't change the string variable that you have.

Comment: Only if he uses code like `string MyFirstSess {get{return (string)Session["WindowName"];}}`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Then he wouldn't have a variable, as his question says he has.

Comment: When I step through it, I can see the variable change.  First it's a lengthy number, then it's NULL.  And then both variables are equal to NULL.  I need the first variable to keep ahold of that lengthy number and not reset itself to NULL.

Comment: @Servy: i just wonder why it behaves different for him and this is the only reason i could think of. He said also _"I have something like"_ not _"I have"_.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Then you're either assigning those values to those variables without realizing it, or you're not looking at the same variables (possibly because you're looking at the fields of different object instances, or locals of different method invocations).

Comment: @TimSchmelter The question in the title indicates that he has a variable.  If he doesn't.  I don't see it as being particularly productive to try and guess as to the specifics of all of the information not given.  There are a *lot* of possible ways to cause this behavior, and quite a lot more if you assume anything stated in the question might be false.

Comment: @JohnnyBones I stand by my answer.  The value of the variable won't change when the session changes.  As to why you'd expect two subsequent fetches of the session value to ever return different results, when you've never set the value between the calls, is beyond me.  They'll always be the same.

Comment: I'm just telling you that when I step through the code when I open a 2nd window, those valuse are different.  MyFirstSess has a number, MySecondSess is NULL.  But when it gets to the "if (MyFirstSess != MySecondSess)" statement, both variables have the same number in them.

Comment: @JohnnyBones That's because you set `MySecondSess` to the same value!

Comment: @TimSchmelter I assume the OP is incorrect in assuming that the values of his fields are changing when the session's values are changing, yes.  I assume that whatever it is he's observing is caused by a different behavior.